# Not zipping correctly

Tags: ubuntu, jar, zip

I'm trying to zip a specific file to visible success, or it might be due to my limited knowledge on zipping files to .jar.

Here are the terminal commands I'm running, as well as what happens after I run them (I'm trying to zip "myfilepath" and everything inside, not the whole directory)

`<sudo zip -r foo.jar /home/administrator/myfilepath/>` = This zips the directory and everything, but when I open the zipped file, I have to navigate through /home/administrator/myfilepath/ to see the files that have been zipped to that zip file.  I only want to see /myfilepath/ and the files and folders in there, not the complete /home/administrator/myfilepath/ directory...

What am I doing wrong?  Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?  I know it's something small I'm missing...

Comment: Sorry, rephrasing my question in comment section..

Comment: sudo zip -r foo.jar /home/administrator/myfilepath/ = This zips the directory and everything, but when I open the zipped file, I have to navigate through /home/administrator/myfilepath/ to see the files that have been zipped to that zip file.  I only want to see /myfilepath/ and the files and folders in there...